# A replacement for nesting if's?

Tags: python, function, syntax, built-in

i'm making a language, and every time a person wants to access a variable, it is with a $ sign. But, on every function I have to have an if, seeing if it's first letter is a $, and every time a parameter is passed, for every parameter I have to do this. It becomes chaotic. I would like to not nest if's, but have it so I can easily apply a function to it, and access this. It is kind of hard to explain, but Ill use some code to explain.

```
def varcmd(cmd, variables):
    if cmd.__len__() < 4:
        print "Too little arguments! str <var> = <string>"
    else:
        if cmd[2] == "=":
            if cmd[3][:1] == "$":
                variables[cmd[1]] = variables[cmd[3][1:]]
            else:
                variables[cmd[1]] = cmd[3]
        else:
            print "Incorrect syntax! str <var> = <string>"
```

As I keep adding to this function, the if's will exponentially increase, and practically every function can take variables, so every function will have tons of if's. Basically, I want something like this:

```
def varcmd(cmd, variables):
    if cmd.__len__() < 4:
        print "Too little arguments! str <var> = <string>"
    else:
        if cmd[2] == "=":
            variables[cmd[1]] = auto_convert_if_var.cmd[3][1:]
        else:
            print "Incorrect syntax! str <var> = <string>"
```

Comment: I don't even know python, but can't you use a loop to iterate over the command arguments?

Comment: Not quite sure of what you want, but it looks like recursion. You can declare recursive functions in Python.

Comment: this is indeed painful! luckily this is a very well understood process.  The thing you need to do here first is tokenize your input.

Comment: One minor suggestion: use `elif:` instead of `else: if:

Comment: Why aren't you using `len(cmd)` instead of `cmd.__len__()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though your needs have gotten complex enough to require building a [parser](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing).